# How to change fade from scroll to element?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want my navigation bar to fade to a solid color when the bottom of it touches the top of a different element. How do I do that through jQuery?

```css
    .navbar {
     background-color: rgba(15, 101, 250, 0.4);
     border-bottom: 3px;
     border-style: solid;
     border-bottom-color: #0f65fa;
     padding-bottom: 10px;
     width: 100%;
     margin-left: 0 auto;
     z-index: 1000;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
     
    }
    
    .navbar::after {
     content: '';
     display: table;
     clear: both;
     }
```

```html
    <div class = "navbar">
      <h1 class = "logo"></h1>
      <a href = "index.html"><img src = "Gold_Coin.png" width = "3.5%" height = "auto" align = "left" style = "margin-top: 0.1%"></a>
      <nav>
       <ul>
        <li><a href = "index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href = "about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href = "outreach.html">Outreach</a></li>
        <li><a href = "media.html">Media</a></li>
        <li><a href = "sponsors.html">Sponsors</a></li>
        <li><a href = "events.html">Events</a></li>
        <li><a href = "login.html">Login</a></li>
       </ul>
      </nav>
     </div>
```

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: On scroll, check scroll position and change colour as necessary. Use CSS transitions for the fade.